# getElementsByClassName is not working

Tags: javascript

I am beginner to JavaScript, Can some one help me whats wrong with my script. I am trying to get all the countries in Asia, that starts with alphabet 'b'. Following is my html document. Following document displays all the countries in asia that starts with letter 'b' in alert box.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Get Element By class name</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="countriesInAsia">
            <h1>Countries in Asia</h1>

            <ol class = "a">
                <li>India</li>
                <li>Indonesia</li>
                <li>Iran</li>
                <li>Iraq</li>
                <li>Israel</li>
            </ol>

            <ol class = "b">
                <li>Bahrain</li>
                <li>Bangladesh</li>
                <li>Bhutan</li>
                <li>Brunei</li>
            </ol>

        </p>

        <p id="countriesInEurope">
            <h1>Countries in Europe</h1>

            <ol class = "a">
                <li>Albania</li>
                <li>Andorra</li>
                <li>Armenia</li>
                <li>Austria</li>
                <li>Azerbaijan</li>
            </ol>

            <ol class = "b">
                <li>Belarus</li>
                <li>Belgium</li>
                <li>Bosnia and Herzegovina</li>
                <li>Bulgaria</li>
            </ol>
        </p>


        <script>
            var countriesInAsia = document.getElementById("countriesInAsia");
            var countries = countriesInAsia.getElementsByClassName("b");
            var message = "Countries in Asia starts with alphabet b are : ";

            for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){
                message = message + countries[i].textContent;
            }

            alert(message);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't to where to start from. You are selecting the `OL` and not the `LI`s.
Try to fetch all children of `OL` and iterate on that.

Comment: Agreed, but textContent should give all the text content in given element ri8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p tag cannot contain ol, so you need to change p to div:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Get Element By class name</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="countriesInAsia">
            <h1>Countries in Asia</h1>

            <ol class = "a">
                <li>India</li>
                <li>Indonesia</li>
                <li>Iran</li>
                <li>Iraq</li>
                <li>Israel</li>
            </ol>

            <ol class = "b">
                <li>Bahrain</li>
                <li>Bangladesh</li>
                <li>Bhutan</li>
                <li>Brunei</li>
            </ol>

        </div>

        <div id="countriesInEurope">
            <h1>Countries in Europe</h1>

            <ol class = "a">
                <li>Albania</li>
                <li>Andorra</li>
                <li>Armenia</li>
                <li>Austria</li>
                <li>Azerbaijan</li>
            </ol>

            <ol class = "b">
                <li>Belarus</li>
                <li>Belgium</li>
                <li>Bosnia and Herzegovina</li>
                <li>Bulgaria</li>
            </ol>
        </div>


        <script>
            var countriesInAsia = document.getElementById("countriesInAsia");
            var countries = countriesInAsia.getElementsByClassName("b");
            var message = "Countries in Asia starts with alphabet b are : ";

            for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){
                message = message + countries[i].textContent;
            }

            alert(message);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this, it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
//var countriesInAsia = document.getElementById("countriesInAsia");
 var countries = document.getElementsByClassName("a");
```

iterate and pick the children of the element

use  document

Comment: hey but I want only from Asia, not from Europe

Answer (score 0):

use `<div>` instead of `<p>`

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Get Element By class name</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="countriesInAsia">
            <h1>Countries in Asia</h1>

            <ol class = "a">
                <li>India</li>
                <li>Indonesia</li>
                <li>Iran</li>
                <li>Iraq</li>
                <li>Israel</li>
            </ol>

            <ol class = "b">
                <li>Bahrain</li>
                <li>Bangladesh</li>
                <li>Bhutan</li>
                <li>Brunei</li>
            </ol>
        </div>

        <div id="countriesInEurope">
            <h1>Countries in Europe</h1>

            <ol class = "a">
                <li>Albania</li>
                <li>Andorra</li>
                <li>Armenia</li>
                <li>Austria</li>
                <li>Azerbaijan</li>
            </ol>

            <ol class = "b">
                <li>Belarus</li>
                <li>Belgium</li>
                <li>Bosnia and Herzegovina</li>
                <li>Bulgaria</li>
            </ol>

        </div>
        <script>
            var countriesInAsia = document.getElementById("countriesInAsia");
            var countries = countriesInAsia.getElementsByClassName("b");
            var message = "Countries in Asia starts with alphabet b are : ";

            for(var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++){
                 message = message + countries[i].textContent;
            }

            alert(message);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```